# Why is my while loop not stopping at the 'at_goal' position?

Tags: while-loop, infinite-loop

[Why is my while loop not stopping at the 'at_goal' position?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbkYj.png)

Hi all,I am learning Python, and I'm somewhat stuck here. Why is this while loop turning into an infinite loop and not stopping at the "at_goal" position?

I expect it to stop at the "at_goal" position when the while loop becomes False.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.